# Permission to buy notifications no longer received

Tags: ios-appstore, notifications, family-sharing

I used to receive the permission notifications when my son tried to buy something from the App Store, but a few weeks ago this just stopped.

I've tried everything: buying from 2 different iPads signed in as him, also signed out and in again. I even checked on my old MacBook to see if the notification were received there, and also on an iPad logged as a me. Nothing seems to receive the notification.

I don't have an iPhone, but I'm pretty sure this doesn't matter. I used to receive the notifications on my MacBook.

I've also checked my notifications settings. They aren't disabled for the Family app, and I get notifications for other things regularly.

The only way he can buy anything is if I disable the "ask to buy" requirement briefly, then re-enable it.

I can't remove and re-add him to the family because he's under 13.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Well, I noticed much later that the notifications did arrive on the iPad and my old MacBook. There was a definite delay though - I was watching both when I tested and nothing arrived timeously. I have no idea why nothing arrived on my primary MacBook though. Will do some more testing shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be logged in on your Mac to the Apple Store to receive Ask to Buy notifications.